# Why docker shows connection timeout error while running hello-world?

Tags: docker

docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
I have tried turning off proxy and vpn that shows different error . when I turn on proxy and vpn it shows different error. I'm using windows 10 .

Comment: Can your reach that url in your browser?

Comment: It shows some json response in that url